# Robolectric sample gives error

Tags: android, robolectric

I have problem running Robolectric [Sample](http://robolectric.org/index.html) app

When I am starting "ant clean test" it gives me such error. How can I fix it? Thanks.

```
-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 37 source files to D:\Builds\RobolectricSample-master\bin\classes
    [javac] Note: D:\Builds\RobolectricSample-master\src\main\java\com\pivotallabs\api\ApiGateway.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

compile.tests:
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Builds\RobolectricSample-master\bin\testClasses
    [javac] Compiling 70 source files to D:\Builds\RobolectricSample-master\bin\testClasses
    [javac] D:\Builds\RobolectricSample-master\src\test\java\com\pivotallabs\injected\TestApplication.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import org.robolectric.TestLifecycleApplication;
    [javac]                       ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class TestLifecycleApplication
    [javac]   location: package org.robolectric
    [javac] D:\Builds\RobolectricSample-master\src\test\java\com\pivotallabs\injected\TestApplication.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public class TestApplication extends com.pivotallabs.injected.Application implements TestLifecycleApplication {
    [javac]                                                                                      ^
    [javac]   symbol: class TestLifecycleApplication
    [javac] D:\Builds\RobolectricSample-master\src\test\java\com\pivotallabs\HomeActivityTest.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(HomeActivity.class).create().get();
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method buildActivity(Class<HomeActivity>)
    [javac]   location: class Robolectric
    [javac] D:\Builds\RobolectricSample-master\src\test\java\com\pivotallabs\NamesActivityTest.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         Activity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(NamesActivity.class)
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method buildActivity(Class<NamesActivity>)
    [javac]   location: class Robolectric
    [javac] D:\Builds\RobolectricSample-master\src\test\java\com\pivotallabs\injected\TestApplication.java:19: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] D:\Builds\RobolectricSample-master\src\test\java\com\pivotallabs\injected\TestApplication.java:23: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] D:\Builds\RobolectricSample-master\src\test\java\com\pivotallabs\injected\TestApplication.java:33: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 7 errors
```

Comment: Have you resolved this? If so, please choose an answer.

Comment: I don't remember how did I resolve this, it was 2 years ago, sorry

Comment: You posted an answer. If you answered your own question, please mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Their example looks like too old. You just need to follow the instruction:
http://robolectric.org/eclipse-quick-start.html

And also you need to download the latest versions of libraries:
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
junit-4.11.jar
robolectric-2.2-20130802.075524-31-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Information is valid at least for August 21 2013.